# Zend Framework 2 translate using gettext a text with variables

Tags: zend-framework2, gettext, zend-translate, xgettext

How I have to do for translate a string as this, where $user contains the user name?

```
    $message = 'Hello ' . $user . ', how are you';
```

If I translate using the follow code, it don't works.

```
    $message = $translator->translate('Hello ' . $user . ', how are you');
```

In my en_EN.po file I have:

```
    msgid "Hello %s, how are you"
    msgstr ""
```

In my es_ES.po file I have:

```
    msgid "Hello %s, how are you"
    msgstr "Hola %s, como estas"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

Try this inside your view:

```
echo sprintf($this->translate("Hello %s, how are you"), $user);
```